# How to generate XML files from SQL Server with hyperlinks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, bcp, xml-generation

I need to create XML files based on data in a base table using SQL Server BCP, however the XML I'm using contains hyperlinks and I think SSMS is interpreting these hyperlinks differently to normal text, so they are not encapsulated correctly within single quotes. Here is the code:

```
SET @Script = '
bcp " ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (''urn:schemas-basda-org:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01'' as po, ''aaaa://xml.aaa.net/K809/k8msgEnvelope'' AS env, ''aaaa://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'' as xsi, default ''aaaa://xml.aaa.net/K809'') SELECT TOP 1 ''aaaa://xml.aaa.net/K809 k8Order.xsd'' as [@xsi:schemaLocation],''   AS [header/env:envelope/env:source/@password],'' AS [header/env:envelope/env:source/@machine],A.SUPPLIER AS [header/env:envelope/env:source/@Endpoint],A.SourceLocation AS [header/env:envelope/env:source/@Branch],'' AS [header/env:envelope/env:destination/@machine],A.SUPPLIER AS [header/env:envelope/env:destination/@Endpoint],A.SourceLocation AS [header/env:envelope/env:destination/@Branch],''ORDERRESPONSE'' AS [header/env:envelope/env:payload],A.FREEATTR3 AS [header/env:envelope/env:cfcompany],''ILDLive'' AS [header/env:envelope/env:service],(select ''ABC 1234567'' AS [po:OrderReferences/po:CrossReference],cast(''<Extensions xmlns="aaaa://xml.aaa.net/k8msg/k8OrderExtensions"><Direct>FALSE</Direct></Extensions>'' as xml).query(''/*''), A.SUPPLIER AS [po:Supplier/po:SupplierReferences/po:BuyersCodeForSupplier], A.EXPDATEPRD AS [po:Delivery/po:PreferredDate],''Test text for Special instructions'' AS [po:Delivery/po:SpecialInstructions],''New item'' AS [po:OrderLine/@TypeDescription],''New'' AS [po:OrderLine/@TypeCode],''Add'' AS [po:OrderLine/@Action],A.ITEM AS [po:OrderLine/po:Product/po:BuyersProductCode],A.ExternalItemMasterID AS [po:OrderLine/po:Product/po:SuppliersProductCode],A.UnitOfMeasureDesc AS [po:OrderLine/po:Quantity/@UOMDescription],A.VolumetricValue AS [po:OrderLine/po:Quantity/@UOMCode],CAST(SUM(A.QEDIT) AS INT) AS [po:OrderLine/po:Quantity/po:Amount],DATEDIFF(DAY,''1989/12/31'',A.EXPDATEPRD) AS [po:OrderLine/po:Delivery/po:PreferredDate]for xml path(''po:PurchaseOrder''), type).query(''declare default element namespace "urn:schemas-basda-org:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01";<PurchaseOrder> { /po:PurchaseOrder/* } </PurchaseOrder>'') as [body] FROM #BaseTemp AS A GROUP BY A.Supplier,A.FREEATTR3,A.SUPPLIER,A.EXPDATEPRD,A.ExternalItemMasterID,A.ITEM,A.VolumetricValue,A.UnitOfMeasureDesc, A.SourceLocation FOR XML PATH(''kmsg'')" queryout "Somedirectory\test.xml" -S GenericServerName -T -w -r -t -c -C 65001
'
EXEC (@Script)
```

The error I'm getting is

> Incorrect syntax near '/'.

With everything being in one line it makes troubleshooting a bit difficult, but the only places I'm using / is in the hyperlinks and the hierarchy structure for the XML layout.

Here's the XML script outside of bcp:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
  'urn:schemas-basda-org:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01' as po,
  'aaaa://xml.aaa.net/K809/k8msgEnvelope' AS env,
  'aaaa://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi,
  default 'aaaa://xml.aaa.net/K809'
)

SELECT TOP 1
    'aaaa://xml.aaa.net/K809 k8Order.xsd' as [@xsi:schemaLocation],
    ''                                      AS [header/env:envelope/env:source/@password],
    ''                                      AS [header/env:envelope/env:source/@machine],
    A.SUPPLIER                              AS [header/env:envelope/env:source/@Endpoint],
    A.SourceLocation                        AS [header/env:envelope/env:source/@Branch],
    ''                                      AS [header/env:envelope/env:destination/@machine],
    A.SUPPLIER                              AS [header/env:envelope/env:destination/@Endpoint],
    A.SourceLocation                        AS [header/env:envelope/env:destination/@Branch],
    'ORDERRESPONSE'                         AS [header/env:envelope/env:payload],
    A.FREEATTR3                             AS [header/env:envelope/env:cfcompany],
    'ILDLive'                               AS [header/env:envelope/env:service],
    (
    select
        'ABC 1234567'                           AS [po:OrderReferences/po:CrossReference],
        cast('<Extensions xmlns="aaaa://xml.aaa.net/k8msg/k8OrderExtensions"><Direct>FALSE</Direct></Extensions>' as xml).query('/*'),
        A.SUPPLIER                              AS [po:Supplier/po:SupplierReferences/po:BuyersCodeForSupplier],
        A.EXPDATEPRD                            AS [po:Delivery/po:PreferredDate],
        'Test text for Special instructions'    AS [po:Delivery/po:SpecialInstructions],
        'New item'                              AS [po:OrderLine/@TypeDescription],
        'New'                                   AS [po:OrderLine/@TypeCode],
        'Add'                                   AS [po:OrderLine/@Action],
        A.ITEM                                  AS [po:OrderLine/po:Product/po:BuyersProductCode],
        A.ExternalItemMasterID                  AS [po:OrderLine/po:Product/po:SuppliersProductCode],
        A.UnitOfMeasureDesc                     AS [po:OrderLine/po:Quantity/@UOMDescription],
        A.VolumetricValue                       AS [po:OrderLine/po:Quantity/@UOMCode],
        CAST(SUM(A.QEDIT) AS INT)               AS [po:OrderLine/po:Quantity/po:Amount],
        DATEDIFF(DAY,'1989/12/31',A.EXPDATEPRD) AS [po:OrderLine/po:Delivery/po:PreferredDate]
    for xml path('po:PurchaseOrder'), type
    ).query('
    declare default element namespace "urn:schemas-basda-org:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01";
    <PurchaseOrder> { /po:PurchaseOrder/* } </PurchaseOrder>') as [body]
FROM BaseTemp AS A
WHERE A.Supplier = @Supplier
AND A.SourceLocation = @Location
GROUP BY A.Supplier,A.FREEATTR3,A.SUPPLIER,A.EXPDATEPRD,A.ExternalItemMasterID,A.ITEM,A.VolumetricValue,A.UnitOfMeasureDesc, A.SourceLocation 
FOR XML PATH('kmsg')
```

Here is the sample data for the base table I'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BaseTemp](
    [RowNo] [bigint] NULL,
    [Supplier] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [SourceLocation] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [FREEATTR3] [varchar](70) NULL,
    [EXPDATEPRD] [int] NULL,
    [Item] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [ExternalItemMasterID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UnitOfMeasureDesc] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [VolumetricValue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [QEDIT] [int] NULL,
    [EXPDATEPRDAsDate] [int] NULL
)
```

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BaseTemp]
           ([RowNo]
           ,[Supplier]
           ,[SourceLocation]
           ,[FREEATTR3]
           ,[EXPDATEPRD]
           ,[Item]
           ,[ExternalItemMasterID]
           ,[UnitOfMeasureDesc]
           ,[VolumetricValue]
           ,[QEDIT]
           ,[EXPDATEPRDAsDate])
     VALUES
           (2
           ,'050025'
           ,'1053'
           ,'01'
           ,'12120'
           ,1153105
           ,'5103'
           ,'Each'
           ,'EA'
           ,1836
           ,20751)
```

Is it the hyperlinks that's causing the error message or is it the XML hierarchy (`\[header/env:envelope/env:source/@password\]`).

I've added `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` to the script to hopefully instruct SQL to use "" and [] as identifiers but to no avail.

Comment: Why do you have a `TOP` when you have no `ORDER BY`, and a `GROUP BY` when no aggregation?

Comment: The TOP was used for testing purposes only, the original base table contains about 400 records so I wanted to test with a single result

Comment: `EXEC` is a synonym for `EXECUTE` and is used to invoke T-SQL code. It looks like you're trying to execute the external [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) tool, you can't do that with [`EXECUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql).

Comment: To avoid pain, i'd recommend putting your XML into a work table and then calling BCP on this table instead of that xml monstrocity. As someone said you can't call bcp using EXECUTE, what you can use is EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp ...' . This proc needs to be enabled because it comes with security issues, but that's life. To really avoid pain, i'd probably use a powershell script to generate your stuff inside sql

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning and siggemannen you were right, I forgot the xp_cmdshell piece. The XML file is now at least trying generate.